# Equations for Classification & Probability Problem

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning

There are 4 containers (classes) to keep balls of different colors (red, green, blue, orange). We know that Container A is for red balls because it contains 80% red balls. B for green balls (90%), and D for orange balls (70%).
This is just a simple illustration of a classification problem that I'm doing.

**My question:** What kind of inference method that I can use to show Container C is for keeping blue balls? Need help to form equations, preferably at academic paper level.

[image]

Comment: most inference techniques deduce that container C is for red balls.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry　yes. how can I include the prior that there's only one container (class) for each color?

Comment: if your stats allow you to decide that ABD are defined, then C is blue by elimination

Comment: also, if every container has 25% of every ball, most inference techniques will fail.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry thanks for the insight. could you point me to the resources of the inference techniques?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure one can deduce the meaning of "is for keeping" from one
example. You have kept track of color counts for each box. But in
your example, it seems best to keep track of the box count for each
color:

Of the 9 red balls, the box with the highest proportion is A with 4.

Of the 7 green balls, the box with the highest proportion is B with 4.

Of the 5 blue balls, the box with the highest proportion is C with 2.

Of the 7 orange balls, the box with the highest proportion is D with 4.

In this particular example, that seems a better way to attain your
objective of connecting colors with boxes. Of course, this method
can get into trouble in various ways, perhaps most obviously if
the number of balls of a particular color were divisible by 4.
And with so few balls, cases must sometimes arise in which there
is not a sensible one-to-one connection.

In some sense what I have done has the flavor of Bayes Theorem.
I have moved from P(color|box) to P(box|color).

Comment: Here, "is for keeping" means the color of a container is assigned based on the color of the most number of balls it has. Your explanation seems to be working. I just need to figure out how to work on P(box|color).

Comment: If this example is a shadow of a larger machine-learning purpose, rules should be governed by that purpose. Are there always equal numbers of boxes and colors? Is this part of your project or someone else's drill exercise?

Comment: This is a simplified version of my machine-learning (classification) project, Container C above is an example of misclassification. Since it's a simplified version, here I just assume number of boxes and colors are always the same.